# Best way to detect all text-like inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm adding keyboard shortcuts to a webpage, but unfortunately I keep running into a recurring bug.  Ideally,  keyboard shortcuts should *not* be activated while the user is typing into a text-like `input`.  Back in the IE6 days this was pretty straight forward, but nowadays there are a wide variety of text-like inputs, such as `input[type=email]`, `input[type=seach]`, `input[type=url]` etc...

Up until now I've used an ever increasing list of selectors to match for all the text-like inputs that I know of.  This is obviously not ideal.  Not only does it hurts performance, it's not future proof.

Is there a better way?

Comment: I think there is just a ***shorter*** way by using `:input` jQuery selector, however it does not select the elements with `contenteditable` set to `true`.

Comment: all inputs have a 'value' property you can filter on.

Answer (score 0):

Most inputs respond to the keyboard in some way (even checkboxes let you toggle them with the space bar and select elements let you search them by typing). I'd exclude all form controls from the keyboard shortcut code.

```
"input, textarea, select, button"
```

Comment: Ideally, if a button or `input[type=submit]` has focus, the keyboard shortcuts should activate.

Comment: Then exclude all inputs except specific ones that you want the JS to trigger on.

Comment: That's an interesting idea.  Essentially, trading false positives for false negatives.  Though there's still concerns about future proofing and perhaps performance.